# Can not authorized connected app on Sandbox

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I have an connected app configured on my prod instance, that I use for my Production, my Staging sandbox (Partial Copy) and my Developer sandbox (Blank Sandbox).

When I use the app credentials (`Client Id`, `Client Secret`) with Authorization Code Flow to authenticate against one of my instances, it works perfectly for Production and my Partial sandbox. It directs me to the authorization/approval screen where I can grant/confirm access and then I can use the access token to make subsequent API calls (using Postman here).

However, this exakt configuration does not work, when I want to authenticate against my Developer sandbox (note: I still use the app credentials from production). It just endlessly re-directs me to the login page, where I can select the usernames (all my sandboxes).

Find a screen attached to see my actual configuration for Staing/Developer. Of course I use `https://login.salesforce.com` to authenticate against my production Org.[image]
This exact configuration works, when I enter my credentials for my partial sandbox (`username@ourdomain.de.partial`) and does not work, when I enter my credentials for my developer sandbox (`username@ourdomain.de.developer`)

Comment: What response do you get (how does the redirect_uri look like) when you authenticate against your Developer sandbox?

Comment: unfortunately, I do not see this. Postman does not show the URI.

Comment: You can see this if you simply use a web browser. Just put this in the address bar "https://<instance_url>/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id_here>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_url>"

Comment: Debugging it in this way would give you more clarity on what parameters your redirect uri contains after user authenticates and approve. Inspect that returned uri and if it contains the "code" parameter, use curl, for example, to request a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say exactly what kind of OAuth configuration you're using. For example, are you using an external provider as an idP, is Salesforce your idP, are you using SAML, do you have some kind of AD integration, or is this a "Federated Authentication" or are you using Delegated Authentication? All of these things determine how your connected app should be configured.

Id you're doing "Federated Authentication Using SAML":

> Sandbox copies are made with federated authentication with SAML disabled. Any configuration information is preserved, except the value for Salesforce Login URL. The Salesforce Login URL is updated to match your sandbox URL, for example https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/, after you re-enable SAML. To enable SAML in the sandbox, from Setup, enter Single Sign-On Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Single Sign-On Settings; then click Edit, and select SAML Enabled.

If you're using postman, I would expect that you've created some kind of custom SSO solution that could consist of pretty much anything you wanted it to be. That makes it that much more difficult for us to advise you on how to configure your connected app for it. In any case, I'd expect you need to configure the connected app in each sandbox after creation to work with your provider.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly. A lot of terms, I am not familiar with. But as I understand it, I use salesforce as identify provider, that is I have an OAuth2.0 App configured in Salesforce (App Manager --> new Connected App) and I use the standard process described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) to connect to the API of my production/sandbox instances. I definitely do not use an Active Directory or some sort of delegation. Does this help?

Comment: I recommend that you use the Help documentation that begins [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_about.htm&type=5). If Salesforce is your identity provider & you're not using Delegated Authentication, it's essential that you utilize MyDomain. SSO will be disabled when you create or refresh a Sandbox. You'll need to configure you connected app (and web service too if using Delegated Auth) in each sandbox when created or refreshed. Ditto for most other configurations.

Comment: I marked this answer as Solution, because MyDomain solved the problem. As soon as I had custom domains for my sandboxes, the authentication of my apps worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for helping to find a needle in a haystack. Enabling SAML ended up being the cure.

Answer (score 0):

As per official [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm&type=0)

**OAuth 2.0 Authentication Endpoints:**

Authorization—https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

Token—https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Revoke—https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke

**Instead of login.salesforce.com, customers can also use the My Domain, community, or test.salesforce.com (sandbox) domains in these endpoints.**

So valid hosts for different environments are:

-- Developer/Production Orgs: login.salesforce.com

-- Sandbox: test.salesforce.com

-- My Domain Enabled: *domain*.*instance*.my.salesforce.com

-- Base Instance: *instance*.salesforce.com (e.g. cs16.salesforce.com)

In your case you should use **test.salesforce.com** host.

Comment: I edited the original post to emphasize that I already knew that and configured everything properly.